# Testing associations with rspec: Category does not have a post_id foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test some associations with RSpec but I get these failures:

```
Category 
   Failure/Error: it {should belong_to :post}
   Expected Category to have a belongs_to association called post (Category does not have  a post_id foreign key.)
 # ./spec/models/category_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Post 
 Failure/Error: it {should have_one (:category)}
   Expected Post to have a has_one association called category (Category does not have a post_id foreign key.)
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  validates_presence_of :author, :category, :post
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

and my tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Post do
  it {should validate_presence_of(:author)}
  it {should validate_presence_of(:post)}
  it {should validate_presence_of(:cathegory)}
  it {should have_one (:category)}  
end

describe Category do
  it {should validate_presence_of :name}
  it {should belong_to :post}
end
```

and my scheme

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121118131441) do

   create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
     t.string   "name"
     t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
     t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
     t.integer  "post_id"
   end

   create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
     t.string   "author"
     t.string   "cathegory"
     t.text     "post"
     t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
     t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
     t.integer  "category_id"
   end

end
```

Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: For a has_one/belongs_to you don't need keys on both sides I'd say that it should be post belongs_to category (and has a category_id column) whereas categories has_many posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your schema, it looks like your database tables are missing the foreign key columns. Creating a migration that adds the following should fix it:

```
add_column :categories, :post_id
add_column :posts, :category_id
```

*Update*

As I said in my comment below, also make sure you run `rake db:test:prepare` to ensure your test database has the most recent schema.

Comment: It looks like you've got the category foreign key, but not the post foreign key so you'll still need `add_column :posts, :category_id`. I would have expected one of the tests to pass, is your test DB out of date with your schema? You can try running `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Well I did what you asked to do, but it didn't work. I put my schema on my post.

Comment: I didn't see the category_id when I first looked at it, but the schema looks correct.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. It worked I just forgot to run rake db:test:prepare to update my test DB.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I updated my answer with the comment I had about running `rake db:test:prepare` just in case someone else stumbles on this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently the same issue, but my schema was fine, the problem was that I were also specifying the `inverse_of` and it was wrongly spelled. It seems that in that case you also get this error.